# Manually specifying styleColorBar limits in DT

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

I am trying to create side-by-side data tables in R using the DT package, and have cell backgrounds shaded using the styleColorBar function shown at the bottom of [this page](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html). However, I want the size of the bar to be proportional to an absolute value, not just values in the table. For example, if I made two tables out of the data below

```
data_1 <- data.frame("Team" = c("Alex", "Beth", "Charlie", "Diane"),
   "Spending_Q1" = c(1000, 500, 1500, 1000))


data_2 <- data.frame("Team" = c("Alex", "Beth", "Charlie", "Diane"),
   "Spending_Q2" = c(3000, 500, 500, 500))
```

I would want the cell showing 3000 to have the longest background bar, and the one with 1500 to have a bar half as long.

Is this possible, or are the bars always proportional to the largest value only in the same data table?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify it in absolute values like this:

```
library(DT)
data_1 <- data.frame("Team" = c("Alex", "Beth", "Charlie", "Diane"),
                     "Spending_Q1" = c(1000, 500, 1500, 1000))

data_2 <- data.frame("Team" = c("Alex", "Beth", "Charlie", "Diane"),
                     "Spending_Q2" = c(3000, 500, 500, 500))

datatable(data_1) %>% formatStyle(names(data_1),
                              background = styleColorBar(1:3000, 'lightblue'),
                              backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
                              backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
                              backgroundPosition = 'center')
datatable(data_2) %>% formatStyle(names(data_2),
                                  background = styleColorBar(1:3000, 'lightblue'),
                                  backgroundSize = '98% 88%',
                                  backgroundRepeat = 'no-repeat',
                                  backgroundPosition = 'center')
```

Is this what you were looking for?